# array sum for two multidimensional array in two diffrent

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [headName] => Cow Loan
                    [netAmount] => 15000
                    [netDeposite] => 1000
                    [deducted] => 480
                    [net_DUE] => 14520
                )            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [headName] => Cow Loan
                    [netAmount] => 4566
                    [netDeposite] => 566
                    [deducted] => 0
                    [net_DUE] => 4566
                )
)
```

How do i sum the multi dimensional array ?

I only want to sum the `deducted` occurance across all arrays

1st array deducted value is 480 and 2nd deducted value is 0 So array sum should be

```
[0] => Array ( [deducted] => 480 )
```

Comment: Please also post what you have tried so far and what didn't work about this approach. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, stackoverflow is not a code writing service ;)

Comment: How do you SUM **which field** or **fields** in this array?

Comment: What you want to sum ?

Comment: Sum of the array of deducted amount

Comment: Come on please be specific. Show us an example of the result that you want and maybe it will all become clear to us

Comment: Give us a proper problem description, and also _show us what you tried_. Your profile says “Web developer.Knowledge in php,cakephp,…”, so that can’t be _nothing_, right?

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1st array deducted value is 480 and 2nd deducted value is 0 
So array sum  should be
 [0] => Array
                (                  
                    [deducted] => 480
                   
                )

Comment: So you want to sum up the values for this specific key only? Well then loop through your outer array (and the inner ones as well, if there can be more than one), access the value under that key, and … sum them up? Where is the actual _problem_ here that you can’t solve?

Comment: How can i add and values in an array ?

Comment: Put that description of your requirement into the QUESTION, others will not look at comments if they find this question in a search

Answer (score 2):

Try as below

```
 $totalDeducted = 0;

 foreach($yourArrayVariable as $key => $value){
     $totalDeducted += $value[0]['deducted'];
 }
```

Comment: Little more care required when writing your answers!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it was by mistake

Comment: There are people here that will jump on little mistakes like that and downvote your answer. Take a few seconds more in writing your answer to check it first, speed is less important than accuracy

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$array = array(
    array(["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>15000,"netDeposite"=>1000,"deducted"=>480,"net_DUE"=>14520]),
    array(["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>4566,"netDeposite"=>566,"deducted"=>0,"net_DUE"=>4566]),
);

$totalDeducted = array_reduce($array, function($sum, $v) {
    $sum += $v[0]['deducted'];
    return $sum;
});

echo $totalDeducted;//480
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
    $array = array(
                array("headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>15000,"netDeposite"=>1000,"deducted"=>480,"net_DUE"=>14520),
                array("headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>4566,"netDeposite"=>566,"deducted"=>0,"net_DUE"=>4566),       
    );


    $deducted=0;
    foreach($array as $values){ 
        $deducted = $deducted+$values['deducted'];
    }

    echo $deducted;
```

Comment: Please look my question then answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not evident that your 2nd level may contain multiple subarrays, but I'll design a solution that will accommodate this possibility.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0nYNu))

```
$array = [
    [["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>15000,"netDeposite"=>1000,"deducted"=>480,"net_DUE"=>14520]],
    [["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>4566,"netDeposite"=>566,"deducted"=>0,"net_DUE"=>4566]],
];

$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $level1) {
    foreach ($level1 as $level2) {
        $total += $level2['deducted'];
    }
}
echo "Deducted: $total";
// Deducted: 480
```

That said, if you only have single subarrays in the second level (only `[0]` exists), then you should restructure your data storage for simpler processing.

Consider this:

```
$array = [
    ["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>15000,"netDeposite"=>1000,"deducted"=>480,"net_DUE"=>14520],
    ["headName"=>'Cow Loan',"netAmount"=>4566,"netDeposite"=>566,"deducted"=>0,"net_DUE"=>4566],
];

echo "Deducted: " , array_sum(array_column($array, 'deducted'));
// Deducted: 480
```